# Building a compiled application with Docker

Tags: c++, deployment, docker, docker-compose

I am building a server, written in C++ and want to deploy it using Docker with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/). What is the "right way" to do it? Should I invoke `make` from Dockerfile or build manually, upload to some server and then `COPY` binaries from Dockerfile?

Comment: Either ways should work, I prefer your first option

Comment: But then you will have development files (such as `-dev` packages) on production machines. And that is... well... not very good, eh?

Comment: No, you can build, then clean and keep only the executables in your container.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I had difficulties automating our build with `docker-compose`, and I ended up using `docker build` for everything:

Three layers for building

> Run → develop → build

Then I copy the build outputs into the 'deploy' image:

> Run → deploy

Four layers to play with:

Run

- Contains any packages required for the application to run - e.g. libsqlite3-0

Develop

- `FROM <projname>:run`
- Contains packages required for the build

  - e.g. g++, cmake, libsqlite3-dev
- Dockerfile executes any external builds

  - e.g. steps to build boost-python3 (not in package manager repositories)

Build

- `FROM <projname>:develop`
- Contains source
- Dockerfile executes internal build (code that changes often)
- Built binaries are copied out of this image for use in deploy

Deploy

- `FROM <projname>:run`
- Output of build copied into image and installed
- `RUN` or `ENTRYPOINT` used to launch the application

The folder structure looks like this:

```
.
├── run
│   └── Dockerfile
├── develop
│   └── Dockerfile
├── build
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── removeOldImages.sh
└── deploy
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── pushImage.sh
```

Setting up the build server means executing:

```
docker build -f run -t <projName>:run
docker build -f develop -t <projName>:develop
```

Each time we make a build, this happens:

```
# Execute the build
docker build -f build -t <projName>:build

# Install build outputs
docker build -f deploy -t <projName>:version

# If successful, push deploy image to dockerhub
docker tag <projName>:<version> <projName>:latest
docker push <projName>:<version>
docker push <projName>:latest
```

I refer people to the Dockerfiles as documentation about how to build/run/install the project.

If a build fails and the output is insufficient for investigation, I can run `/bin/bash` in `<projname>:build` and poke around to see what went wrong.

---

I put together [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/MatrixManAtYrService/lifecycle-snapshots) around this idea. It works well for C++, but you could probably use it for anything.

---

I haven't explored the feature, but @TaylorEdmiston pointed out that my pattern here is quite similar to [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), which I didn't know about when I came up with this. It looks like a more elegant (and better documented) way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Seems pretty cool. I'd love to see your Github repo with the HelloWorld C++ example of this (with all 4 docker files and the two shell files...) Thanks for sharing.

Comment: I love the idea, but I seem to be lacking some understanding of how to actually use your example repo to do something like this myself. I cloned your repo (actually sildeag's fork, with the Ubuntu 18.04 fix) and I ran `./build/snap.sh` which seemed to work, but how do I actually access the built artifact? How do I run the program now that it's compiled? Is it compiled?

Comment: Your comment helped me learn that the project was broken when dockerhub's `ubuntu:latest` stopped pointing to 16.04 and started pointing to 18.04.  I've fixed it, so running the snap scripts should now work (it will print out a few commands that you can use to verify that it's working).  If it's still broken for you, feel free to file an issue.

Comment: @stevendesu As to your question (now that it's fixed)  I'd proceed by making sure lifecycle-snapshots builds and runs the sample project and that you understand what's going on at each stage.  Then remove the submodule reference and add a new one to point at the repo you want to build instead.  Then make changes to the various Dockerfiles so that they set up environments that are relevant to your project instead of the sample.  The build artifact is either the `deploy` image or the deb file generated by the build image.  See deploy/snap.sh for how it is plucked from the build image.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you use 4 separate Dockerfiles here as opposed to 1 Dockerfile with 4 stages using [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)?

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston It's because I didn't know that feature existed (which perhaps I can be forgiven for, since it was release four months after I answered the question).  Thanks for pointing it out, I'll make an edit.

Comment: @MatrixManAtYrService That makes sense.  Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 6):

## Update

For anyone visiting this question after 2017, please see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55990911/3618671) by [fuglede](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5085211/fuglede) about using [multi-stage Docker builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/), that is really a better solution than my answer (below) from 2015, well before that was available.

---

## Old answer

The way I would do it is to run your build outside of your container and only copy the output of the build (your binary and any necessary libraries) into your container. You can then upload your container to a container registry (e.g., use a hosted one or run your own), and then pull from that registry onto your production machines. Thus, the flow could look like this:

1. build binary
2. test / sanity-check the *binary* itself
3. build container image with binary
4. test / sanity-check the *container image* with the binary
5. upload to container registry
6. deploy to staging/test/qa, pulling from the registry
7. deploy to prod, pulling from the registry

Since it's important that you test before production deployment, you want to test exactly the same thing that you will deploy in production, so you don't want to extract or modify the Docker image in any way after building it.

I would not run the build *inside* the container you plan to deploy in prod, as then your container will have all sorts of additional artifacts (such as temporary build outputs, tooling, etc.) that you don't need in production and needlessly grow your container image with things you won't use for your deployment.

Comment: This solution isn't completely inline with Docker philosophy. This can lead to the same old problem "Oh!! but it worked on my machine". Unless the C++ application has few or no dependencies and doesn't rely on shared object files (.so files) this solution will lead to linking against incorrect versions of dependencies – blueskin 49 mins ago

Comment: @blueskin – Thanks for bringing this up. I've thought about this as well; I think one solution would be to use two containers: one for building, with a volume mapped in to export the output to the host, and the second container for deployment has none of the build artifacts or temporary files, but just includes the final build outputs. Thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

My recommendation would be to completely develop, build and test on the container itself. This ensures the Docker philosophy that the developer's environment is the same as the production environment, see *[The Modern Developer Workstation on MacOS with Docker](https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/06/20/docker-osx-mac/)*.

Especially, in case of C++ applications where there are usually dependencies with shared libraries/object files.

I don't think there exists a standardized development process for developing, testing and deploying C++ applications on Docker, yet.

To answer your question, the way we do it as of now is, to treat the container as your development environment and enforce a set of practices on the team like:

1. Our codebase (except config files) always lives on shared volume (on local machine) (versioned on Git)
2. Shared/dependent libraries, binaries, etc. **always** live in the container
3. Build & test in the container and **before committing the image, clean unwanted object files, libraries, etc., and ensure `docker diff` changes are as expected**.
4. Changes/updates to environment, including shared libraries, dependencies, are always documented and communicated with the team.

Answer (score 6):

While the solutions presented in the other answers -- and in particular the suggestion of Misha Brukman in the comments to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34519173/5085211) about using one Dockerfile for development and one for production -- would be considered idiomatic at the time the question was written, it should be noted that the problems they are trying to solve -- and in particular the issue of cleaning up the build environment to reduce image size while still being able to use the same container environment in development and production -- have effectively been solved by *[multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/)*, which were introduced in Docker 17.05.

The idea here would be to split up the Dockerfile into two parts, one that's based on your favorite development environment, such as a fully-fledged Debian base image, which is concerned with creating the binaries that you want to deploy at the end of the day, and another which simply runs the built binaries in a minimal environment, such as Alpine.

This way you avoid possible discrepancies between development and production environments as alluded to by blueskin in one of the comments, while still ensuring that your production image is not polluted with development tooling.

The documentation provides the following example of a multi-stage build of a Go application, which you would then adopt to a C++ development environment (with one gotcha being that Alpine uses [musl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musl) so you have to be careful when linking in your development environment).

```
FROM golang:1.7.3
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/
RUN go get -d -v golang.org/x/net/html  
COPY app.go .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o app .

FROM alpine:latest  
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
WORKDIR /root/
COPY --from=0 /go/src/github.com/alexellis/href-counter/app .
CMD ["./app"]
```